# Inheritance for protected member

Tags: java, inheritance

I still do not understand why "Acc obj = new Test()" will not give access to the protected integer in the superclass but "Test obj = new Test()" will give access.

Acc obj = new Test(); <- NO acces to protected integer

Test obj = new Test(); <- YES acces to protected integer

```
package p1; 
public class Acc {
int p;
private int q;
[b]protected int r;[/b]
public int s;
}
```

---

```
package p2;
import p1.Acc;
public class Test extends Acc {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // insert LINE
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show where exactly you try to access `r` and what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java only allows the subclass to access protected members, that are in a different package, if it is "responsible for the implementation".... ie. if it can determine the type IS-A the subclass. If you want to access the protected member, while using a superclass reference, you will need to cast it first.